# Почему не работает ссылка при клике в нижнюю её часть?

Tags: html, css

Есть [ссылка-кнопка](https://jsfiddle.net/07LjaomL/2/). У нее есть эффект нажатия, кнопка на 3 пикселя сдвигается вниз при нажатии. Проблема в том, что если нажимать снизу книпки (тень у внутреннего блока кнопки), то переход на страницу не срабатывает. Эта проблема есть в Safari, Firefox. Возможно в других браузерах. Из-за чего это может быть и как можно поправить?

**HTML:**

```
<a class="download_button_block js-send_btn" href="http://google.com/">
    <span class="download_button">
        <span class="icon">
            <span class="arrow"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="text">Скачать видеоуроки</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.download_button_block {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 476px;
    height: 88px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
}

.download_button {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f7c62f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-animation: shadow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: shadow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.download_button:hover {
    background: #fed146;
}

.download_button_block:active .download_button {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.download_button .icon {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 11px 0 0 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 63px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d69517;
    background: url(../images/download_button__icon.png) 29px center no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

.download_button .arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(../images/download_button__arrow.png) center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 29px;
    -webkit-animation: arrow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: arrow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.download_button .text {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 76px);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 85px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/07LjaomL/3/

Comment: Ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Как это не изменилось? :) Кнопка не нажимается при наведении на тень, курсор не изменяется в тени. А на самой кнопке у вас все отлично работает. P.S. Хотя у меня и на тени отлично ссылка нажимается (по консоли смотрю) в FF 47.

Comment: Проблема была в том, что при нажатии на тень по ссылке не было перехода. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на тень и кнопка нажималась, и ссылка работала.

Comment: И также происходит при нажатии вверху кнопки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте ссылке - `overflow: hidden;`, **возможно** из-за этого у Вас проблема (вн. блок с `float: left;` ):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.download_button_block {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 476px;
    height: 88px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
  
    overflow: hidden;
}

.download_button {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f7c62f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-animation: shadow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: shadow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.download_button:hover {
    background: #fed146;
}

.download_button_block:active .download_button {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.download_button .icon {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 11px 0 0 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 63px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d69517;
    background: url(../images/download_button__icon.png) 29px center no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

.download_button .arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(../images/download_button__arrow.png) center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 29px;
    -webkit-animation: arrow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: arrow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.download_button .text {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 76px);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 85px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<a class="download_button_block js-send_btn" href="http://google.com/">
    <span class="download_button">
        <span class="icon">
            <span class="arrow"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="text">Скачать видеоуроки</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

Либо еще такой вариант:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.download_button_block {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 476px;
    height: 88px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
  
 overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.download_button_block a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.download_button {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #f7c62f;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 0 #b26303, 0 0 0 1px #ffba56 inset;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    -moz-text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
    outline: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-animation: shadow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: shadow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.download_button:hover {
    background: #fed146;
}

.download_button_block:active .download_button {
    margin: 3px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.download_button .icon {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 11px 0 0 0;
    width: 75px;
    height: 63px;
    border-right: 1px solid #d69517;
    background: url(../images/download_button__icon.png) 29px center no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

.download_button .arrow {
    display: block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 19px;
    background: url(../images/download_button__arrow.png) center no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 29px;
    -webkit-animation: arrow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
    animation: arrow  1.5s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.download_button .text {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 76px);
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 85px;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="download_button_block js-send_btn" >
    <a href="http://google.com/"></a>
    <span class="download_button">
        <span class="icon">
            <span class="arrow"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="text">Скачать видеоуроки</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

смысл: *поместить ссылку с переходом на стр. `http://google.com/`, поместить с абсолютом поверх всего содержимого кнопки (чтобы уже точно сработала).*

Comment: Вариант с overflow:hidden не помогает. Сделал по второму варианту.